# Magento 2.2.x Product Image automatic Resize when height more than 1200px

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resizing

Magento 2.2.x Product Image automatic resize when height more than 1200px

Might be default m2 bug.

LMK how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check Officla Dev Docs. 
Go through below link may be its help you :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#resize-catalog-images